# how to check wordpress custom table is empty or not

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

**This question about wordpress cutom table..**
I am creating a plugin I want to check a table named `wp_school_post` table empty or not.

See my code below which throws the following error

```
Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\getwp\wp-content\plugins\getwp_P\schools_post_function.php on line 7

**filled**
```

My code:

```
function schools_post_function()
{
//  echo "Sachool POST function";
    global $wpdb;
    $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT postid from wp_school_post WHERE `postid` IS NOT NULL");
    if(mysql_num_rows($result=='0'))
    {
        echo "not filled";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "filled";

    }
}
```

Comment: @Shell please read the questions code before mark as duplicate thank you

Comment: Agree with you why stackoverflows other user direct mark as duplicate without read does they have answer ?

Comment: #Gerald Schneider tell me how this question duplicate ? this is wp question not mysql question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this :)

```
<?php
function schools_post_function()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT postid from wp_school_post WHERE `postid` IS NOT NULL");
    if(count($result) == 0)
    {
        echo "not filled";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "filled";

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: _Try this_ answers are low-value here.  Please explain all answers that you post.

Answer (score 4):

You could simplify your code and save resources using [`get_var`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_a_Variable) instead to obtain the row count:

```
$count = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM {$wpdb->prefix}school_post WHERE postid IS NOT NULL");

if($count == 0)
{
    // No rows.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using wordpress's `WPDB` class `get_results()` method will give you the data in form of object/array, you just need to check the count for `$result` which holds the result from `get_results()`

```
if(count($result) == 0){
// your code
}
```

[`See WPDB usage details`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)